# How to allow user to rename the file while downloading using Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I need one help. I need to rename the file while downloading using Javascript/Angular.js. Actually, I have one functionality convert HTML table to excel sheet and download it. I am explaining my code below.

```
$scope.generateExcelSheet=function(){
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
      var table='exportable';
      var name='Report';
     // console.log('table',table,name);
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
}
```

Here I need before the file will download it will ask the user to rename the file and then download it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the window location to your data url, create an `<a>` element (it doesn't need to be part of the DOM, it's enough to use `document.createElement('a')`), put URL in the `href` property to the base64 url and add a `download` attribute with any file name you care for. Then call `click()` on the created anchor.

This will work on any browser that [supports the download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download), which means - most modern browsers, with the exception of IE11 (but works on Edge) and Safari.

Comment: Can you mearge your idea with my code. I am not fully clear.

Comment: which place requires comment? You create a URL (by `uri + base64(format(template, ctx));`). Instead of assigning it to `window.location`, perform the steps described by me. Create an anchor, set its href, set its download, call click().

Comment: OK,Let me to do it.

Comment: @ fdreger : i did like this `var anchr=document.createElement('a');
           anchr.href=uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
           anchr.click();` but it did not ask user to change file name.

Comment: The code will _not_ ask for the filename. You can add any filename you wish by setting the `download` attribute (e.g. `anchr.download = 'whatever.xls'`). Asking user for the filename will depend on the UX of your application (the basic would be, say, `anchr.download = prompt('enter filename', 'new.xls')`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122518/discussion-between-subhra-and-fdreger).